# VBA "Left"-function as integer

Tags: vba

been playing around with the "left"-function in VBA and noticed that the result is stored as a string. For example:

```
Left(ws2.range("C2").value,3)
```

Where ws2 is some worksheet and c2 is some cell in ws2 containing, say, 1234.

The left function would then return "123" but it would be formated as a string. This in turn causes errors for me when i try to access a directories key with this string (which is not possible). I've found a workaround where I :

```
dim tag as integer
tag = Left(ws2.range("C2").value,3)
```

This would cause the tag with the value 123 to be stored as an integer which I then can use for accessing the directory.

But i'm wondering if it's possible to modify the "left"-function to return values as integers? or any other format for that matter (long, variant, range, whatever)

**Notice that I have figured out a solution but I thought it might be helpful to others and/or a interesting discussion.**

Comment: `cint(left(ws2.range("C2").value,3))` would be "better" as you're still relying on VBA to make the conversion for you, also checking the output first to work out if you in fact need to use a long maybe.  Also checking the input string is numeric first of all would also be a good check.

Comment: You'd have to write your own `Left` function as you can't modify the existing one.  Possibly simpler to just write `tag = CInt(Left(ws2.range("C2").value,3)) `

Answer (score 0):

For this it is easiest to use `Cint()` function. There is no need to modify functions, you can always create yours.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it would be to use the `Cint()` function to cast an expression to an integer.

For details see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9(v=vs.84).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here are some more conversion functions:

```
CInt() 'convert to integer
CLng() 'convert to long (long is preferred over integer since integer only has 2 bytes in VBA)
CDbl() 'convert to double
CDec() 'convert to decimal (variable has to be declared as variant)
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it an answer :)

`cint(left(ws2.range("C2").value,3))` would be "better" as you're still relying on VBA to make the conversion for you, also checking the output first to work out if you in fact need to use a long maybe. Also checking the input string is numeric first of all would also be a good check.

Answer (score 0):

using cint

```
function IntLeft(byval value as string, byval length as integer) as Integer
   IntLeft=0 'default if non numeric
   if isnumeric(value) then
      IntLeft=cint(left(value,length))
   end if
end function
```

using int

```
function IntLeft(byval value as string, byval length as integer) as Integer   
   IntLeft=int(left(value,length))   'int returns the first numbers as an int, 0 if no numbers
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Abs function instead to return the left function as integer.

i.e., Abs(Left(ws2.range("C2").value,3))